# Is it advisable to use `add_rewrite_rule()` to serve a custom page?

Tags: customization, rewrite-rules

I have a page called "dynamic" that's not stored in the post table at all (not a post, page or custom post type of any sort); the reason being is all the data is completely dynamic based on `$_GET` requests.

This is a pretty close representation of how I've done it

```
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'add_custom_rewrite' ) );
add_action( 'parse_request', array( $this, 'custom_requests' ) );
add_filter( 'query_vars', array( $this, 'custom_query_vars' ) );

function add_custom_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'dynamic/?$',
        'index.php?dynamic=true',
        'top'
    );
}

function custom_requests( $wp ) {
    if( !empty( $wp->query_vars['dynamic'] ) ) {
        dynamic( $_GET );
    }
}

function dynamic( $get ) {
    // ... do stuff with $get
    load_template( get_template_directory() . '/dynamic.php' );
    exit;
}
```

Now I ask this question as the page seems to finish early. It loads up the `wp_footer()` function and all the good stuff, but doesn't show an admin bar like all the other standard pages.

Is there a better way to approach this issue; maybe using a real post type stored in the DB and referencing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead using the `template_redirect` hook.

Here I have a blogpost on using that approach:

http://www.tomjn.com/386/content-without-posts/

I've had no issues with the admin toolbar using this method.

It includes a helper class:

```
<?php

/**
 * A helper class to implement arbitrary content at arbitrary URLs without a supporting post or page.
 * Inherit from this class and implement the render_page method
 * 
 * @author: Tom J Nowell ww.tomjn.com
 * @License: GPL 2+
 */
abstract class Tomjn_Custom_Page {

    /**
     * Saves the options container and sets up some WP hooks
     */
    public function __construct( $options ) {
        $this->options = $options;

        // add our rewrite rules
        add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', array( $this, 'custom_page_generate_rewrite_rules' ) );
        // add our custom query variable to the whitelist
        add_filter( 'query_vars', array( $this, 'custom_page_query_vars' ) );
        // dont pull in a full listing of posts in the main query, there's no need
        // ( you can comment this out if you're not using a theme template to render content )
        add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', array( $this, 'custom_page_paging_issue' ) );
        // call render_page() when needed
        add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'custom_page_template_redirect' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Add our rewrite rules
     */
    function custom_page_generate_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
        $pagename = $this->options['pagename'];
        $custom_page_rules = array(
            $this->options['url'] => 'index.php?custom_page='.$pagename.'&posts_per_page=1&paged=1'
        );
        $wp_rewrite->rules = $custom_page_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    }

    /**
     * Filter that inserts our query variable into the $wp_query
     */
    function custom_page_query_vars( $qvars ) {
        $qvars[] = 'custom_page';
        return $qvars;
    }

    /**
     * fix page loops if pulling in a theme template
     */
    function custom_page_paging_issue( $query ) {
        if ( !empty( $query->query_vars['custom_page'] ) ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Filter that maps the query variable to a template
     */
    function custom_page_template_redirect() {
        $pagename = $this->options['pagename'];
        global $wp_query;
        $custom_page = $wp_query->query_vars['custom_page'];
        if ( $custom_page == $pagename ) {
            // we've found our page, call render_page and exit
            $this->render_page();
            exit;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays the content, extend this class and implement this function as needed
     */
    public abstract function render_page();

}
```

Using it is as simple as:

```
require_once( 'custom_page.php' );

class Hello_World_Page extends Tomjn_Custom_Page {
    public function render_page() {
        echo 'hello world!';
    }
}

$helloworld = new Hello_World_Page( array(
    'url'       => 'helloworld',
    'pagename'  => 'helloworld'
));
```